# Comparator loses voltage when connected to mosfet

Tags: batteries, mosfet, comparator, discharge, over-discharge

[image][image]I want to make a discharger for 18650 batteries so I can store them at a specific voltage.

I built a comparator (LM393) with a voltage reference to 3.8V at the inverting input and the voltage of the battery on the noninverting input. The circuit has its own power supply (9V battery). Grounds are connected.

The comparator works fine, but when I connect it to the gate of the mosfet, its output voltage drops from around 9V to just 1V or so.

Also when I disconected the power from the Drain, the voltage appeared again.

I am using a pullup resistor on the output of the comparator (10k, tried 1k and it was the same). I also tried to put the load (5V 5W resistor) on the Drain or on the source, both worked the same. The mosfet can be opened, but the voltage on the non inverting input must be around 6V instead of the 3.8 and higher. And when I apply the higher voltage, at some point the mosfet opens and the voltage on the non inverting input drops to that 3.9V. The mosfet is IRLZ44N.

Please tell me what's going on and what I am doing wrong.
[image]

Comment: Use the tool, edit your question and draw a schematic with the tool. Thanks

Comment: yes! You probably built something pretty clever, but I really don't know what – without a schematic showing exactly what you've built, we couldn't even sensibly guess at what is happening. Please use the built-in schematic editor that comes with the question editor.

Comment: are you pulling down the gate? there's not a good reason the voltage should drop when connected to an insulated gate.

Comment: Iam actually pulling it down, because the comparator just pulls it down, without the pullup resistor i have constant 0 at the output

Comment: Miskate in your schematic? R4 should go to 9V.

Comment: Yeah it was just mistake in the scheme, fixed.

Comment: Have you looked at the output of the comparator on a scope?  Maybe it's oscillating, not just dropping in voltage.  You could (and probably should) try adding some hysteresis to the comparator.  Do you have good local decoupling on the comparator supply?

Comment: Actualy I dont have any capacitors anywhere and dont know where to add them. And I havent look on the output with osciloscope. Also, how do i add the hysteresis?

Comment: It's probably oscillating then. When MOSFET turns ON, load current makes battery voltage drop, so comparator turns it OFF, battery voltage rises, comparator turns it ON...

Comment: Hysteresis calculator - https://www.random-science-tools.com/electronics/schmitt-trigger-calculator.htm - add something like 50-100mV hysteresis. Also add capacitor between comparator supply pins, like 100nF.

Comment: I have to say that Iam not using batteries right now, Iam instead using 2 variable power supplies for testing. And Iam using special IO comparator, not a OpAmp as a comparator

Comment: Add 10k to 100k in series with feedback IC3A3 pin3 then >1uF on that input to gnd.

Comment: added 100k and 1uf as you said. At 3.9V on the powersupply acting as a 18650, the voltage on the gate is 1.23V, when the 18650 power supply reaches somewhere around 4.5V, there is 8.33V at the gate

Comment: But i connected my osciloscope and it seems like its oscilating. 18650power supply is at 4.2V and my multimeter on the gate shows 2.6V and Ill add the screen of the osciloscope to the question

Comment: Why are you using a comparator, rather than an opamp?

Comment: Because i was told its better and it can output 0V without simetrical power supply

Comment: Most reasonable opamps made in the last 10 years will be able to do rail to rail (i.e. output 0V without a symmetrical power supply). I dont think you want a comparator, in order to do what you're trying to do. The LMC7101 may work for you.

Comment: I have some OpAmp and it doesnt support rail to rail and I have tried it and hava the same problem as I have now

Comment: so how do I remove these oscilations?

Answer (score 1):

> Add hysteresis to comparator level to stop oscillation

Some of the comments have correctly identified the need for hysteresis in your circuit because the battery terminal voltage will increase when you turn off Q1.
First, what you got right in your design:

1. A comparator is the correct choice for the task (not an opamp). The LM393 is quite appropriate.
2. You implemented a good stable voltage reference using the TL341L

One potentially easy way to implement the hysteresis is to place it in series with your voltage sensing input.
Under normal discharge operation you want the switching point to be accurately 3.8V, so you want to implement asymmetrical hysteresis. As the battery terminal voltage moves below the 3.8V threshold and Q1 turns off you want to reduce the sensed voltage by whatever hysteresis you want.

The circuit would then look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdGJCN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With R3 and R4 as shown you will have about 100mV hysteresis. The discharger may still turn on and off several times as the battery voltage recovers, but eventually the terminal voltage will closely approach the 3.8V reference. R3 could be made an adjustable resistor if you wanted.

Comment: I tried that and it still doesnt work. Till 4.6V there are little waves on the osciloscope and on 4.6V and higher there are big waves that open the mosfet a little bit and then it smoothens out at 5.6V

Comment: Then that is a simulation artifact since the battery is NOT going to rise to 4.6V. It's up to ou to make sure your simulation elements are realistic.

Comment: I have everythink on my breadboard, Iam not doing any simulations. Iam using laboratory powersupply as a "battery" and as I sayed, when I join the real battery with 4.2V the mosfet wont even open

Comment: OK....do you really think a power supply reacts the same as a chemically based battery. Turning on M1 depends on the measured voltage so if the battery voltage is around 4.2V then the device should turn on. However there is something major wrong with the use a power supply since you should NEVER get voltages above 4.2V and at 4.2V M1 should turn on.

Comment: I know that power supply doesnt act the same as the battery, but I just want to test out, if it works. If I join the battery and its voltage is higher that 3.8V the mosfet should open and discharge the battery throu the R5, when its 3.8V or below, it should close the mosfet. So Iam using the powersupply to imitate the battery voltage, I can easily change the voltage of the powersupply to test if the circuit works. So i dont think it is the problem that Iam using the powersupply instead of the battery.

Comment: I just want you to know it should turn on even if the battery is 4V or 3.9V It should turn on and open the mosfet everytime there is more than 3.8V on the battery terminal. Sadly the mosfet doesnt open till the 4.6V, but when I disconect the mosfet, there is 8V on the comparator when there is more than 3.8V on the battery terminals, but when I add the mosfet the voltage drops

Comment: Please don't use open and close to describe the FET state. If the voltage you feed to the circuit is above 3.8V the FET should be ON. Now if you power supply can't deliver at least 0.75A, then you have a problem. If you have a CV/CC power supply ensure you have the CC limit set high enough. If you disconnect the FET you should be able to test the threshold voltage. The comparator output should be either  close to 9V or very close to zero as you test the threshold.

Comment: my powersupply can deliver that amout of current and yes, the comparator is functioning correctly but if I connect its output to the gate of the mosfet (doesnt matter if its on or off) the voltage drops and the mosfet stays of till the 4.6V

Comment: Perhaps you have damage it.

Comment: You mean the mosfet?

Comment: Yes, the FET gate should not drop the drive voltage since it is essentially just a capacitance.